# How to get rid of Undefined symbol error in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have this 4 errors in Xcode. They seem to be the same thing.

Undefined symbol: _pb_decode
Undefined symbol: _pb_encode
Undefined symbol: _pb_istream_from_buffer
Undefined symbol: _pb_release

I don't know where it's from. Help!

I tried searching on the internet and deleting derived data

Comment: You are missing a library, most likely. Something in your app is called decode and encode and they don't exist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.